# Loop Through Org Employee ID Arrays using Begin With Filter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, filter

I have a report with a summary page that has all of the employee ID's listed and each employee belongs to a specific group. I'm trying to have my macro filter through the arrays for each group with each array containing the EID numbers and then export the filtered data into a separate sheet.
The issue I'm running into is, I have one group that contains about 20 EIDs and I'm using the "begin with filtering method" such as "1156*" which only seems to work with up to two values in the array only. I'm using this method because the EID's in the summary page are shown for example "11569-Org1". Any help to work around this would be appreciated.

```
Dim EIDNumbers(1 to 3) As Variant
EIDNumbers(1) = Array("16799*", "17900*")
EIDNumbers(2) = "22222*"
EIDNumbers(3) = Array("88888*","90000*","88444*")

For n = UBound(GroupNames) To LBound(GroupNames) Step -1
   If IsArray(EIDNumbers(n)) Then 
    dataRG.AutoFilter 11, EIDNumbers(n), xlFilterValues
   Else
    dataRG.AutoFilter 11, EIDNumbers(n)
   End If

Set fdataRG = mainWS.Range("A1").EntireColumn
fdataCT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, fdataRG) - 1
If fdataCT > 1 Then ' add additional subws
    Set subWS = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=mainWS)
    subWS.Name = OrgNames(n)
   
    Set dfcell = subWS.Range("A1")
   
    dataRG.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell

End If
Next n
```

Comment: Wildcard filter only works with up to two values - you'd need to find some other approach.  If your data isn't huge then a row-by-row check might be easier to manage.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams my data is about a couple thousand rows.

Answer (score 0):

### Filter Data When More Than Two WildCard Criteria

```vb
Dim LeftEIDs(1 To 3) As Variant
LeftEIDs(1) = Array("16799*", "17900*")
LeftEIDs(2) = Array("22222*")
LeftEIDs(3) = Array("88888*", "90000*", "88444*")

' Write the data (the EIDs) from the EID column to the keys of a dictionary.

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

Dim Data: Data = dataRG.Columns(11).Value
Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(EIDs, 1)
Dim r As Long, cString As String

For r = 2 To rCount
    cString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
    If Len(cString) > 0 Then dict(cString) = Empty
Next r

' Write the matches per group to the keys of another dictionary
' and use them to filter by the EID column and to copy
' the data to a new worksheet.

Dim cDict As Object: Set cDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
cDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

Dim LeftEID, eKey, e As Long, n As Long

If mainWS.FilterMode Then mainWS.ShowAllData ' not sure about 'mainWS'!?

For n = UBound(LeftEIDs) To LBound(LeftEIDs) Step -1
    For Each eKey In dict.Keys
        For Each LeftEID In LeftEIDs(n)
            If eKey Like LeftEID Then
                cDict(eKey) = Empty
                dict.Remove eKey
                Exit For
            End If
        Next LeftEID
    Next eKey
    If cDict.Count > 0 Then
        dataRG.AutoFilter 11, cDict.Keys, xlFilterValues
        Set subWS = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=mainWS)
        subWS.Name = OrgNames(n)
        Set dfcell = subWS.Range("A1")
        dataRG.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        mainWS.ShowAllData ' not sure about 'mainWS'!?
        cDict.RemoveAll
    End If
Next n

'mainWS.autfiltermode = False ' not sure about 'mainWS'!?
```

Comment: I keep getting a "For Each control variable must be a Variant or Object" error at line 20 "For Each LeftEID In LeftEIDs(n)". I assumed it was because LeftEID was declared as Long and not a Variant but when I changed it to variant I get the error, "Type Mismatch". Can you assist?

Comment: If you haven't replaced `EIDNumbers(2) = "22222*"` with `EIDNumbers(2) = Array("22222*")`, that is the error you will get (if it occurs in the same line as before). Otherwise, let me know the values of the variables when the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. The code isn't running correctly, it is returning a cDict.Count of 0, preventing the next steps of filtering the main worksheet's data by the EIDs. I think it's because it's only looping through eKey counts of the lower and upperbounds of the EIDs which is a count of n=3? Is it supposed to loop throw all the rows to determine if the eKey is like the LeftEIDNumbers?